# Generar prefijo dinámico para cambiar IDs de botones con función JS

Tags: javascript

Necesito cambiar dinámicamente las IDs de botones en diferentes páginas traducidas a lenguajes.

Tengo varios botones, un para de ejemplos:

```
<button id="Home_a_Servicios">Servicios</button>
<button id="Home_a_Contacto">Contacto</button>
```

Lo que yo quiero es cambiar el ID de los botones por:

```
<button id="EngUK_Home_a_Servicios">Services</button>
<button id="EngUK_Home_a_Contacto">Contact Us</button>

<button id="FraFR_Home_a_Servicios">Services</button>
<button id="FraFR_Home_a_Contacto">Se Contacter</button>

<button id="DeuDE_Home_a_Servicios">Services</button>
<button id="DeuDE_Home_a_Contacto">Kontakt</button>
```

Hasta el momento, la función que estoy escribiendo va así, pero no está funcionando, mi conocimiento de JS es muy básico:

```
    /* Change ids */
function changeids() { document.getElementById('EngUK_' + id);} changeids;

    
/* Change ids */
function changeids() { document.getElementById('FraFR_' + id);} changeids;
    
    
/* Change ids */
function changeids() { document.getElementById('DeuDE_' + id);} changeids;
```

Los sitios están desarrollados en Wordpress, por lo que la función estaría agregada por cada uno en el functions.php del tema.

Agradeceré su ayuda.

Saludos.

Answer (score 0):

como te va?

Primero que nada tu sintaxis esta casi correcta.

```
/* Change ids */
function changeids(){
  document.getElementById('EngUK_' + id)
} 
changeids
```

Para invocar a una función te falta el paréntesis.
`changeids()`.

Otro pequeño error es que dentro de la función `changeids()` estas utilizando la variable `id` la cual de momento no existe, a no ser que la tengas declarada de forma global como en el ejemplo que te dejo más abajo.

Para acceder al id de un elemento podes usar simplemente `elemento.id` para cambiarlo o asignarle un nuevo valor podes usar el signo `=` osea `elemento.id = 'nuevoID'`
Aquí podes leer más sobre la propiedad [id](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) de un elemento

Y pues lo último por agregar seria seguir las convenciones para nombrar a las variables `changesids` deberia de ser `changeIds`
Aquí te dejo un [link](https://google.github.io/styleguide/jsguide.html#naming) con más info acerca de las convenciones.

Espero que el ejemplo de abajo te sirva de guía. Y pues cualquier cosa aquí estamos para darte una mano.

Saludos!

```js
let baseServiciosID = 'Home_a_Servicios'
let baseContactoID = 'Home_a_Contacto'

function changeId(id) { 
  // Asignamos el boton a una variable
  let buttonEl = document.getElementById('EngUK_' + id)
  console.log('Boton seleccionado es: ', buttonEl.innerText)
  console.log('Su id es: ', buttonEl.id)
  
  // Se asigna una nueva ID
  buttonEl.id = 'DeuDE_Home_a_Servicios'
  console.log('Ahora su id es: ', buttonEl.id)
  
  // y aqui por si necesitas que la funcion te retorne el boton.
  // return buttonEl
}

// Invocas o llamas a la funcion y le pasas el parametro baseServiciosID
changeId(baseServiciosID)
```

```html
<button id="EngUK_Home_a_Servicios">Services</button>
<button id="EngUK_Home_a_Contacto">Contact Us</button>

<button id="FraFR_Home_a_Servicios">Services</button>
<button id="FraFR_Home_a_Contacto">Se Contacter</button>

<button id="DeuDE_Home_a_Servicios">Services</button>
<button id="DeuDE_Home_a_Contacto">Kontakt</button>
```